# How do I make python processes run with correct process name?

Tags: python, linux

I have a few long term processes and temporary processes in Python. While shell and C programs run under their own names, all Python processes run as 'python filename.py', which makes it tough to identify processes.

How can I make python processes show up as 'logserver.py' or such in Linux? I use Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a shebang to the Python file in question, make the Python file executable (e.g. by `chmod a+x ./logserver.py`) and start it directly by `./logserver.py`.

A shebang is a line telling the kernel which interpreter to use.  It's simply a line like `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: recommend to use the line:  `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be explicit, or change the name while the script is running, there's a [library for that](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setproctitle) on PyPI.

```
 import setproctitle
 setproctitle.setproctitle('logserver')
```

Making the script executable and starting it directly is often enough, though.

Comment: As much as the other answer is right. This is an amazing module.