# Python: compile into an Unix commandline app

Tags: python, unix, command-line

I am not sure if I searched for the wrong terms, but I could not find much on this subject. I am on osx and I'd like to compile a commandline python script into a small commandline app, that I can put into usr/local/bin so I can call it from anywhere. Is there a straighforward way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: that should be prety easy just put `#!/path/to/python` ( or `#!/usr/bin/env python`) at the start of you're script, then make it an executable using chmod ( `chmod +x path/to/script` ) you should then be able to call it

Comment: You want to be able to execute it like `my_script` instead of eg. `./my_script.py`?

Comment: I asked a bit similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976926/how-do-i-make-python-processes-run-with-correct-process-name. You would want to make that script executable. Cant help with the "compilation" part though: please tell us your intention.

Comment: well I don't necessarily wan't to compile it, I just want to make it accessible fron anywhere.- I would prefer it if it would be accesible with my_script instead of ./my_script.py. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to rename your file from `filename.py` to `filename` and add this line to the top of the file.

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

You may also need to set the executable bit on the file, which may be set using `chmod +x` on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

On Unix it works usually in the following way:

1. Put `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line of your `.py` script.
2. Add execution permissions to the file (using `chmod`).
3. Execute the script from command line, eg. by providing `./my_script.py` when in the same directory.

What else do you need?

Answer (score 2):

A Python script is already a "command line app" that you can put anywhere.

Just set the first line of your script to be a proper shebang pointing to your Python interpreter 
For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

(Or wherever OS X puts its Python interpreter), 
set your script with the executble attributes, and put it on your bin folder

(it does not need to end in ".py" either)

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

in the very beginning of your script
or 
write shell script that will lauch your script like

```
#!/bin/sh
python path_to_your_script/your_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

As almost everybody said, you can turn your script executable by adding the following line at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and setting it to be executable:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Another alternative, is to convert your script into a **native executable**.
For that, you may use [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), depending on your target platform.